# RelativeLayout.BELOW doesn't work in programmatically created RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm creating a Layout programmatically consisting of a RelativeLayout and some TextViews. I want them to be placed like two columns like following example:

```
textview0  textview1
textview2  textview3
textview4  textview5
```

and the following LayoutParameters is applied to them:

width: WRAP_CONTENT

height: WRAP_CONTENT

and rules for example textview4:

RelativeLayout.BELOW, textview3.getId()

RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE

and rules for textview5:

RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textview4.getId()

RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, textview4.getId()

This ensures that the contents in column to the right can be wrapped but textviews below it is still showing fine, as it's placed below the textview that could be wrapped.

Well, when I try this out I get it to work for the first two rows of textviews, they are placed as they should, but then  I add a third one and that one get placed on the same row as it should be placed below. And I cant figure out what's wrong.

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
rl.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
rl.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView0.setLayoutParams(lp0);
rl.addView(textView0);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView0.getId());
lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, textView0.getId());
lp1.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
textView1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
rl.addView(textView1);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView1.getId());
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
rl.addView(textView2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView2.getId());
lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, textView2.getId());
lp3.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
textView3.setLayoutParams(lp3);
rl.addView(textView3);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp4.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView3.getId());
lp4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView4.setLayoutParams(lp4);
rl.addView(textView4);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp5 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp5.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView4.getId());
lp5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, textView4.getId());
lp5.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
textView5.setLayoutParams(lp5);
rl.addView(textView5);
```

So the example code above results in textView4 being placed above textView2 even though it should be placed below it, ruled by LayoutParameters for textView3. I can't see anything wrong with this code, and I have debugged it to ensure that the ID's was unique among the textviews and they are.

Any suggestions, I'm kind of stuck!

Comment: Just curious - why would you want to do this in code instead of in an XML layout file?

Comment: Surely this... `lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView1.getId());` should be using `textView0.getId()` as you want `textView2` directly below `textView0` and not directly below `textView1` ??? The same would apply to `textView4` which should go directly below `textView2` and not `textView3`

Comment: @Squonk, no it should be below textView1, as I explained earlier, this ensures that the textviews in the "right column" can wrap their content without interfering with the below textviews. If it for example the lp2.addRule() should be set below textView0 then if textView1 wraps it contents then it's content should be displayed above the textviews below. So it should be this way.

Comment: This should be within a dialog, and I've tried to build this up as an xml layout once and then Override DialogFragment.onCreateView, inflating the xml layout view, but this didn't look good, as you dont get the default buttons. So I decided to create my dialog using onCreateDialog and AlertDialog.Builder instead, you get all the buttons look right this way. To bad you cant inflate a view in onCreateDialog, otherwise I would never have done this programmatically

Comment: You should use `TableLayout`

Comment: Solved this problem by building up my dialog programmatically in DialogFragment.onCreateDialog() using LinearLayouts and TextViews, worked fine and I got to keep the default Android buttons in the dialog.